# How can I find which functions are being called by which functions with ts-morph or the typescript compiler API?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api, ts-morph

Using `ts-morph`, we can get function declarations in a source file by calling `sourceFile.getFunctions()`.

Calling `functionDeclaration.getChildrenOfKind(SyntaxKind.CallExpression)` on function declarations then lets us find all function calls in the body of the corresponding functions.

What I'm missing is - how can I find the function declarations corresponding to the functions being called in the call expressions?